# angular 2 + OAuth 1.0 + signature with '+' character

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth, http-get

I am integrating OAuth 1.0 in Angular2 application. I am using simple http.get method and it is working fine until the signature doesn't have '+' character.
 Eg: Signature = I8RxZ0I78ALux4T683QYxTFE9vQ=

If signature contains '+' character then i am getting status as 400 and response as signature invalid error. 
Eg: Signature = uyF+uHFTg5KjwCZxP5J6g9yOYpw=

If I debug the application on browser, the signature shown correctly on the url, but the quest string parameter instead of '+' char it shows 'whitespace'.

**oauth_signature:uyF uHFTg5KjwCZxP5J6g9yOYpw=**

Can anybody has any idea about this?

Thanks

can

Comment: can you add more code so that we can help you easily

Answer (score 0):

you must set your token in authorization header then send your http request (get or post)

Comment: yes, i did it. And it is working fine with the signature which doesn't have '+' character. The problem is, if the signature contains '+' character then it is not working

Comment: if you set in request header does not any problem